IMO $1997$ Problem $3$
Originally, I found this problem in a Maths Workshop (not exam!!). After I searched online, I was redirected to the IMO $1997$ Problem $3$.

Let $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$ be real numbers satisfying the conditions: $|x_1 + x_2 + · · · + x_n| = 1$ and $|x_i|≤(n+1)/2$ for $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$. Show that there exists a permutation $y_1, y_2, . . . , y_n$ of $x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n$ such that $|y_1 + 2y_2 + · · · + ny_n| ≤ (n + 1)/2$.

Just for reference, my mathematical skills have not reached the IMO level so if you would like to provide a solution, I would appreciate it if it was slightly simplified (if you could explain some of the steps.)
Anyways, I tried to tackle the problem by assuming $ x_1 ≤ x_2 ≤ · · · ≤ x_n.$
Then we create 2 sums $A$ and $B$:
The largest possible value of the sum in question is
$A = x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + · · · + nx_n.$
While the smallest value is
$B = nx_1 + (n − 1)x_2 + · · · + x_n.$ This is the reverse of sum $A$.
I am now stuck here and I am unable to proceed any further. Any contributions to help me solve this problem would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Hint: The average value of the weighted sum across all the permutations is $\frac{n+1}{2}(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n)=\pm \frac{n+1}{2}$ so $B \le  \frac{n+1}{2}$ and $A \ge  -\frac{n+1}{2}$, and if neither $A$ nor $B$ provide an example in the desired interval then $B \lt  -\frac{n+1}{2} \lt \frac{n+1}{2} \lt A$.  Then show you can move from $B$ to $A$ in several steps each changing the weighted sum by no more than $n+1$ and so at some stage you must be in the desired interval.

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS threads Reals with absolute sum 1, permutation smaller than n+1/2 and A combinatorics problem.
